# How does dirac's delta function appear in transition rate in fermi's golden rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

In the context of time dependent perturbation theory as in 8.06, video's code L 11.2 from mit ocw, I can't see any Dirac delta function appear anywhere. When I read about ["Fermi's Golden Rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule). This equation appears at some point:
$$\Gamma _{if}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|<\psi _f|H'|\psi_i>|
^2\delta(E_f-E_i+\hbar\omega).$$

How does it appear? What is the meaning for the Dirac delta in it? What happens if the final state isn't discrete? Can I just multiply the transition rate $\Gamma$ by the density of final states $\rho(E_f)$ so that it will become the real solution of that system?

In other words, will $\Gamma$ become
$$\Gamma_{i->f}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|<\psi _f|H'|\psi_i>|^2\rho(E_f)$$ or
$$ \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|<\psi _f|H'|\psi_i>|^2\rho(E_f)\delta(E_f-E_i+\hbar\omega)$$
(i.e. if $\Gamma$ requires a Dirac delta).

Comment: It is just there to ensure conservation of energy.

Comment: [Quantum Physics 3](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/video-lectures/time-dependent-perturbation-theory/) @ohneVal

Comment: just edit the question, is not for me, it is for the community... hehehe

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743562/2451

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac Delta function shows that $\Gamma_{ij}$ is zero except when $E_f = E_i -\hbar\omega$. Thus the photon energy $\hbar\omega$ has to be equal to the difference $E_i - E_f$ for the transition to happen.

Comment: When $\delta(0)=\infty$ the transition is infinity. Is it mean the state is change instantly?

Comment: The Dirac delta should definitely not be interpreted like that in this case (it never really should).

Comment: The idea is that this should be integrated over an interval of photon energies, which will then lead to the specific photon energy for which the transition is valid being singled out.

Comment: $\Delta(0)=\infty$ in a point (0), this does not has to do with the speed of change.